# How can search a column by date format?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query according the day and month at the same time condition between 2 columns in a period of time like this:

Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa2fe/1)

Here is the information:

```
CREATE TABLE clients
 (date_birth date, [date_anniversary] date)
;

INSERT INTO clients
 ([date_birth], [date_anniversary])
VALUES
('1911-01-04',NULL ),('1921-01-05',NULL ),('1931-01-06',NULL ),('1941-01-07',NULL ),
('1951-01-08',NULL ),('1961-01-09',NULL ),('1971-01-10',NULL ),('1981-01-11',NULL ),
('1991-01-12',NULL ),(NULL, '1998-02-13'),(NULL, '1999-02-14'),(NULL, '2000-02-15'),
(NULL, '2001-02-16'),(NULL, '2002-02-17'),(NULL, '2003-02-18'),(NULL, '2004-02-19'),
(NULL, '2005-02-20'),(NULL, '2006-02-21');
```

Here is the condition:

```
since "04-01" until "13-02"
show all from clients where date_birth BETWEEN "04-01" AND "13-02" OR date_anniversary "04-01" AND "13-02"
```

This should be the output:

```
('1911-01-04',NULL ),
('1921-01-05',NULL ),
('1931-01-06',NULL ),
('1941-01-07',NULL ),
('1951-01-08',NULL ),
('1961-01-09',NULL ),
('1971-01-10',NULL ),
('1981-01-11',NULL ),
('1991-01-12',NULL ),
(NULL, '1998-02-13'),
```

I tried this but is just for month:

```
select date_birth from clients 
where month(date_birth) BETWEEN '00' AND '01'
```

And also tried:

```
SET @date1 := 01-14;
SET @date2 := 02-20;

select date_birth from clients
where date_birth BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: Is this really MySQL?

Comment: You have provided MSSQL Fiddle and your question is tagged with Mysql which vendor you are using ?

Comment: Yes is mysql but in "condition" I traslated it in human words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by using Mysql's month and day functions

```
SELECT date_birth ,date_anniversary
FROM clients
WHERE 
(
MONTH(date_birth) >= 01 AND MONTH(date_birth) <= 01
AND DAY(date_birth) >= 01 AND DAY(date_birth) <= 31
)
OR
(
MONTH(date_anniversary) >= 01 AND MONTH(date_anniversary) <= 01
AND DAY(date_anniversary) >= 01 AND DAY(date_anniversary) <= 31
)
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8599/9)

using Mysql's date_format function just format your columns by day and month can compare with the provided range of same format,also provide your parameters as in this '%m-%d' format

```
select date_birth ,date_anniversary
from clients
where date_format(date_birth,'%m-%d') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '01-31'
or
date_format(date_anniversary,'%m-%d') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '01-31'
```

[Fiddle demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8599/11)

Storing values in variables

```
SET @start:='01-01';
SET @end:='01-31';
SELECT date_birth ,date_anniversary
FROM clients
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_birth,'%m-%d') BETWEEN @start AND @end
OR
DATE_FORMAT(date_anniversary,'%m-%d') BETWEEN @start AND @end
```

[Fiddle demo 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8599/15)

Comment: `(month >= 1) and (month <= 1)`? Why not just `month = 1`?

Comment: @MarcB there can be a range of months like from jan to march so i can't use = operator

Comment: Thanks M Khalid, Seems that is the only way , +1 and +thanks =) ...question closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL try this:

```
SELECT 
    date_birth 
    ,date_anniversary
FROM clients
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_birth, '%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('1900-01-04', '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('1900-02-13', '%m-%d')
    OR DATE_FORMAT(date_anniversary, '%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('1900-01-04', '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('1900-02-13', '%m-%d')
```

If you are using MSSQL e posted into wrong subject try to google a DATE_FORMAT() function equivalent on it.